# Test databases in gitlab ci

Tags: mysql, gitlab, gitlab-ci

I would like to use test databases for feature branches.

Of course it would be best to create a gitlab ci environment on the fly (review apps style) and also create a test database on the target system with the same name. Unfortunately, this is not possible because the MySQL databases in the target system have fixed names, like `xxx_1`, `xxx_2` etc. and this cannot be changed without moving to a different hosting provider.

So I would like to do something like "grab an empty test data base from the given `xxx_n` and then empty it again when the branch is deleted".

How could this be handled with gitlab ci?

Can I set a variable on the project that says "feature branch Y already uses database `xxx_4`"?

Or should I put a table into the test database to store this information?

Comment: Hmm. I'm not sure I fully understand the issue. When you deploy the review environment, how is the database name configured in the app?  If the hosting provider is creating fixed names for you, I feel like they _should_ also provide a mechanism for discovering that name. Usually you can connect to the database and enumerate the (owned) databases (I think in MySQL `SHOW GRANTS` might be the way). So if the user only has a grant to one particular DB, that should be easy to parse out. Let me know if that helps or if I'm missing something important.

Comment: It is a PHP application. I can deploy the different test versions into different directories. The database name will be added on deployment, read from a gitlab ci variable of the respective environment.

Comment: I think I understand the problem you have and have suggested a solution... but let me know if I've missed anything major.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using dynamic environments/variables and stop jobs might be able to do the trick. Stop jobs will run when the environment is "stopped" -- in the case of feature branches without associated MRs, [when the feature branch is deleted](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/environments/index.html#stop-an-environment-when-a-branch-is-deleted) (or if there is an open MR for the review app, when the MR is merged or closed)

> Can I set a variable on the project that says "feature branch Y already uses database xxx_4"?

One way may be to put the db name directly in the environment name. Then the Environments API keeps track of this.

```yaml
stages:
  - pre-deploy
  - deploy

determine_database:
  stage: pre-deploy
  image: python:3.9-slim
  script:
    - pip install python-gitlab
    - database_name=$(determine-database) # determine what database names are not currently in use
    - echo "database_name=${database_name}" > vars.env
  artifacts:
    reports:  # automatically set $database_name variable in subsequent jobs
      dotenv: "vars.env"

deploy_review_app:
  stage: deploy
  environment:
    name: review/$CI_COMMIT_REF_SLUG/$database_name
    on_stop: teardown
  script:
    - echo "deploying review app for $CI_COMMIT_REF with database name configuration $database_name"
    - ... # steps to actually do the deploy

teardown: # this will trigger when the environment is stopped
  stage: deploy
  variables:
    GIT_STRATEGY: none  # ensures this works even if the branch is deleted
  when: manual
  script:
    - echo "tearing down test database $database_name"
    - ... # actual script steps to stop env and cleanup database
  environment:
    name: review/$CI_COMMIT_REF_SLUG/$database_name
    action: "stop"
```

The implementation of the `determine-database` command may have to connect to your database to determine what database names are available (or perhaps you have a set of these provisioned in advance). You can then inspect the GitLab [environments API](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/api/environments.html) to see what database names are still in use (since it's baked into the environment name).

For example, you might have something like this. Here, I am using the python-gitlab API wrapper just because it's most familiar to me, but the same principle can be applied to any method of calling the GitLab REST API.

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python3

import gitlab
import os, sys, random

GITLAB_URL = os.environ['CI_SERVER_URL']
PROJECT_TOKEN = os.environ['MY_PROJECT_TOKEN'] # you generate and add this to your CI/CD variables!
PROJECT_ID = os.environ['CI_PROJECT_ID']

DATABASE_NAMES = ['xxx_1', 'xxx_2', 'xxx_3'] # or determine this programmatically by connecting to the DB

gl = gitlab.Gitlab(GITLAB_URL, private_token=PROJECT_TOKEN)

in_use_databases = []

project = gl.projects.get(PROJECT_ID)
for environment in project.environments.list(state='available', all=True):
    # the in-use database name is the string after the last '/' in the env name
    in_use_db_name = environment.name.split('/')[-1]
    in_use_databases.append(in_use_db_name)

available_databases = [name for name in DATABASE_NAMES if name not in in_use_databases]

if not available_databases: # bail if all databases are in use
  print('FATAL. no available databases', file=sys.stderr)
  raise SystemExit(1)



# otherwise pick one and output to stdout
db_name = random.choice(available_databses)
# optionally you could prepare the database here, too, instead of relying on the `on_stop` job.
print(db_name)
```

There is a potential concurrency problem here (two runs of `determine_database` concurrently on different branches can potentially select the same db twice before either finish) but that could be addressed with [resource locks](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/resource_groups/).